# ath9k stacks date in ocb mode

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, driver

I have a WPEA-121N card connected to nitrogen SOM v2 with NXP i.MX 6 dual.
For handling WPEA-121N I'm using ath9k driver.
Linux version used: 18.04.3  and kernel version: 4.14

I need to receive data from the wireless interface in the ocb mode. The message is sent every 300ms.
In my program I use the read function:
 `read(mSocket, mPacket, sizeof(mPacket));`
 from  `<unistd.h>`.
However my program doesn't receive any mesage for 2 seconds and  then 7 messages come at onece (almost with the same timestamp).

When I run Wireshark on wireless interface I also see messages coming in those packets (7 messages every 2 seconds). 
When I run strace on SOM v2 I receive one sendmsg message (ID - 54) and 4 times recvmsg messages (2 with ID 54 and two with ID - 53) and multiple gettimeofday messages.

This makes me think that the problem must be with ath9k driver. I tried to debug it but could not understand receive flow.

I also tried to run this program on Ubuntu on x86 architecture and it receives messages with a proper frequency.

UPDATE:

[Block diagaram of i.MX 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfciD.png)

When I run: sudo  lspci -vv
I get in PCI bridge:

```
DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
```

full result:

```html
ubuntu@bionic-xfce:~$ sudo lspci -vv
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. Device abcd (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 309
 Region 0: Memory at 01000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=ff, sec-latency=0
 Memory behind bridge: 01100000-011fffff
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 01200000-012fffff
 Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at 01300000 [disabled] [size=64K]
 BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
  PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
 Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
  Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
  Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
  Address: 0000000062040000  Data: 0000
  Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
 Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
  DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
   ExtTag- RBE+
  DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
   RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
   MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
  DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
  LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 unlimited
   ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
  LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
   ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
  LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
  RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna+ CRSVisible-
  RootCap: CRSVisible-
  RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
  DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported ARIFwd-
  DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled ARIFwd-
  LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
    Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
    Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
  LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
    EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
 Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
  UESta: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  UEMsk: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  CESta: RxErr+ BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
  CEMsk: RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
  AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
 Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
  Caps: LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
  Arb: Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
  Ctrl: ArbSelect=Fixed
  Status: InProgress-
  VC0: Caps: PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
   Arb: Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
   Ctrl: Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
   Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 341
 Region 0: Memory at 01100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at 01200000 [disabled] [size=64K]
 Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
  Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
  Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
  Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
  Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
 Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
  DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
   ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
  DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
   RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
   MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
  DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
  LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
   ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
  LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
   ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
  LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
  DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
  DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
  LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
    Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
    Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
  LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
    EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
 Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
  UESta: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  UEMsk: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
  CESta: RxErr+ BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
  CEMsk: RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
  AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
 Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
  Caps: LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
  Arb: Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
  Ctrl: ArbSelect=Fixed
  Status: InProgress-
  VC0: Caps: PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
   Arb: Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
   Ctrl: Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
   Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
 Capabilities: [300 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Do you know what does it mean?

WPEA-121N card:  http://www.sparklan.com/p2-products-detail.php?PKey=25c0Ma0Cj9d7HopM4rLAPTAIGkPKeW3bIVVxmd7DnA&WPEA-121N
NitrogenSOMv2: https://boundarydevices.com/product/nitrogen6-som-v2/

Comment: The ath9k is normally on a PCI bus.  The NXP iMx6 may/may not have this bus and the card is connected by another means.  This bus configuration may be the issue.  This is done by boundary devices or who ever created the device tree you use to enable the driver.  It is not clear from the link what the carrier board with the ath9k is.

Comment: The NXP iMx6 uses PCI express as shown in the link. Can this be the couse of my problem?

Comment: It is possible.  If the driver is in the mainline as it seems, then some bus issue seems more probably.  I realized you were using PCIe after I read some other papers on the iMx.  Thanks for the explicit info.  That said, wifi drivers are extremely complex.  It is also possible the driver has an issue; just not certain.

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks for reply. I checked my PCI bus on my x86 computer (motherboard: HP EliteDesk  800 g1 usdt) and it also uses PCIExpress (Both ARM and x86 use 2nd version of PCIe) . The frequency of incoming data had been also checked on another x86 computer so it makes me think the problem is related to the architecture of  computer. Any idea what can be done to fix it?

Comment: @artlessnoise i also checked  lspci -vv and it showed some errors on ARM. Details in question above. Perhaps it is the cause of my problem.

Comment: The `lspci -vv` may not be an issue.  I would `diff` to the `lspci -vv` PC which works and see what is different.  If they are the same, then it is more likely a driver issues.  It is also quite common that drivers may have races which on only exposed on a significantly slower CPU (the arch makes some sort of difference in call order of irq/workqueue, etc).